# JQuery loop to append text not appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am try to create a loop with jQuery 2.1.0 that appends a paragraph each loop. This is my code so far

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var hobby = prompt("tell me one of your hobbies!");
  $("body").append("<p>" + hobby + "</p>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so the prompt comes up and works fine but then it doesn't append... and it doesn't loop. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet, where it seems to work fine - at least for me in Chrome. Could you please describe what your issue is more clearly.

Comment: Same result as Rory described. Your code seems to work. Could you give more information regarding your issue, e.g. which browsers etc.

Comment: Same here. It's working on Firefox 53 and 55.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use native js.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 var hobby = prompt("tell me one of your hobbies!");
 var p = document.createElement('p');
 p.innerHTML = hobby;
 document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
for(var i = 0; i<3;i++){
var hobby = prompt("tell me one of your hobbies!");
var newP = $("<p>");
newP.text(hobby);
$("body").append(newP);}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```